# How can I communicate to the adapter from another activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, adapter

I have an adapter inside a fragment that belongs to an Activity A, from this adapter I open the detail of an element in an Activity B. How can I tell the adapter of Activity A that it has to update the list of the adapter that is in a fragment of Activity B?

This is the method I have inside the activity:

```kotlin
private fun setOnClickFavoriteListener(recipe: RecipesItem?) {
        binding?.recipeDetailContainerFavoriteButton?.setOnClickListener {
            if (recipe?.isFavorite == true) {
                isFavorite = false
                viewModel.setFavoriteRecipe(recipe.id, isFavorite)
                binding?.recipeDetailImgFavoriteButton?.setColorFilter(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        R.color.silver
                    )
                )
            } else {
                isFavorite = true
                viewModel.setFavoriteRecipe(recipe?.id, isFavorite)
                binding?.recipeDetailImgFavoriteButton?.setColorFilter(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        R.color.sunglo
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my adapter which is not in the same activity, so I have no communication between them:

```kotlin
class FavoritesAdapter(private val favorites: List<RecipesItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoritesViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FavoritesViewHolder {
        val binding = FavoritesRowBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return FavoritesViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FavoritesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(favorites[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return favorites.size
    }
}

class FavoritesViewHolder(private val binding: FavoritesRowBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(recipesItem: RecipesItem) {
        binding.favoritesRowImgRecipeImage.load(recipesItem.imageURL)
        binding.favoritesRowLabelRecipeName.text = recipesItem.name
        binding.favoritesRowLabelTime.text = binding.root.context.getString(
            R.string.recipe_time,
            recipesItem.time
        )
        binding.favoritesRowLabelDifficult.text = recipesItem.difficult
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            val bundle = bundleOf(RECIPE_BUNDLE to recipesItem)
            val intent = Intent(binding.root.context, RecipeDetailActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtras(bundle)
            binding.root.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put the fetching of the favourites list in the onResume, but it does a strange effect where it briefly shows the empty list image and then shows the updated list:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FavoritesFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: FavoritesViewModel by viewModels()
    private var binding: FragmentFavoritesBinding? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentFavoritesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding?.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (activity as DashboardActivity).showToolbar(true)
        (activity as DashboardActivity).setToolbarTitle(getString(R.string.option_menu_favorite))
    }

    private fun initObservers() {
        viewModel.favoritesLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { favorites ->
            if (favorites.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.hide()
                binding?.favoritesGroupEmptyRecipes?.show()

            } else {
                binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.show()
                binding?.favoritesGroupEmptyRecipes?.hide()
                val adapter = FavoritesAdapter(favorites)
                binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
                    context,
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                    false
                )
                binding?.favoritesRecyclerViewRecipes?.adapter = adapter
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewModel.getFavoritesFromDatabase()
        initObservers()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        binding = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From The adapter in Fragment of Activity 'A' you send the Item in the intent bundle as you did.
Then from Activity 'B' you handle this bundle and send the item to the Fragment in Activity 'B' then the fragment will render the item in its adapter.
I hope I understand your question right

Comment: But I have no way of communicating with the adapter...

Comment: Sorry Which adapter you mean here you don't have communication with

Comment: When I am in the detail activity I have no communication with the adapter that is inside the favourites fragment in another activity.

Comment: You can start Activity 'B' from Activity 'A' using startActivityForResult .. and in Fragment 'B' using its context you setResult so it returns back to Fragment in Activity 'A' and handle the result in onActivityResult then edit what you want in the adapter